# Entity Framework compilation error. Class cannot be used as scalar property, because it does not have a getter and setter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, fluent-interface, database-relations

With Code First approach and implementing a database for an existing system. Therefore I cannot make alot of changes to the existing code. That's why I'm using Fluent API and Entity Framework.

When I'm trying to implement a new class (`Vector`) which is used by several other classes, I'm getting a compilation error:

```
The relationship 'Price_Data' was not loaded because the type 'Vector' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The property 'Item' of type 'Vector' in the assembly 'Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be used as a scalar property because it does not have both a getter and setter.
```

Since I'm fairly new to .NET (coming from Java) I do not know where to start looking for the error.

Does anyone here know why, and how to fix this?

Comment: We need to see some code, sorry

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I'm sorry, but I cannot show you any of the code. I do think now that there could be something with my `Vector` class uses a `double[] Data` property, which has an `[XmlArrayItem("d")]` annotation above. Could it be as simple as figuring out how to store an array of Double?

Comment: We need to see some code.. create some to repro the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this was happening.

`Vector`has an `Indexer`property, aka `public var this[]`. 
Thanks to [Another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232615/ignore-this-property-with-code-first-fluent-api-column-item-is-added).

As of now, the Fluent API cannot handle this kind of issue, and the simpliest way of adressing this is to use Data Annotation and `[NotMapped]`.

The resulting code would be something like:

```
class Vector
{
    [NotMapped]
    public var this[]
    {
    }
}
```

Would like to thank everyone for taken their time trying to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the error message carefully, the problem is very clear:

> The property 'Item' of type 'Vector' in the assembly 'Core,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be used
>   as a scalar property because it does not have both a getter and
>   setter.

Your class `Vector` has a property `Item` which does have a getter or a setter, but not both, and Entity Framework needs read-write properties to work correctly.

### Unrelated note: suggestion

If your domain objects don't have their properties marked as virtual (i.e. `public virtual string PropertyName`), you're not going to take advantage of lazy-loading, meaning that your queries will load the entire result set which ends up in a very inefficient data I/O (*more network traffic, greater load times and, at the end of the day, slower applications/services*).

Comment: The strange thing is that `Vector` does not have any `Item` properties. Is this something EF could have created? There's an XML attribute named `[XmlArrayItem("d")]`, could this have something to do about it?

Comment: @zo0mbie Sadly I'm not a wizard ;) Will you post the `Vector` class source code?

Comment: On the unrelated note: Can I add virtual to my domain objects without any impact on the existing system? Since this is changes to the Core module of the system, you can imagine how critical this part of the system is for changes.

Comment: @zo0mbie Absolutely. No impact. It's just about telling the compiler that these properties can be polymorphic, or in other words: you're allowing overrides on them. Nothing more :)

Comment: I cannot show the source code for this system :( could it be that the getter for the reference to `Vector` is not simple but complex? `get { return _data = _data ?? Vector.Empty; }` `_data` is a `Vector` class.

Comment: @zo0mbie If you can't share a bit of your code, why don't you make a "similar piece of code", something like pseudo-code? Anyway, does this property have a `set { ... }`?

Comment: It is to complex to make into a pseudo-code. All those properties have getters and setters. Though the getters are more complex than just getting the objects. They are all like the example above. `get {return data = data ?? Vector.Empty;}`

Comment: @zo0mbie It'll be hard if you request assistance in a site like SO and you can't share anything... Can you post the source of how you make the mapping with Code First? I mean, I'd be nice to see how you did the mapping of the Price_Data relationship.

Comment: I appreciate you for taken your time. I do not map any relationship, I'm trying, but right now I tried to make EF map the relationship itself. I'm currently working on the mapping.

Comment: @zo0mbie You'll need to share that mapping code or no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

If I may be so bold, the error kind of clearly says: The property Item in the type Vector (in assembly Core) does not have both a `get` and `set` clause.  It would need one if you want to use it with EF.

Comment: I've answered this in the comment above here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084718/entity-framework-compilation-error-class-cannot-be-used-as-scalar-property-bec#comment21217200_15084762)

Comment: The `Item` is not defined in the class, but it shows up int the database table, but I do not know where in the system this column is related to a property. Is it possible to find out where EF columns are created from? Something like `View Code`...